# Remove Headers and Footers

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I'm looking to find ways to remove header, footer text in a pdf with document ai, I couldn't find in any API documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/ProcessOptions)

I'm using `OCR_PROCESSOR` and tried to `enable_native_pdf_parsing` but there is no option in any config for header/footer in layout.

```py
     process_options = documentai.ProcessOptions(
            ocr_config=documentai.OcrConfig(
                enable_native_pdf_parsing=True,
                enable_symbol=True,
            )
        )
```

Can someone please advise on this?

Comment: PDF documents do not have the concept of "header" and "footer", especially if you're using OCR to scan a printed document.  All it knows is "these characters were located at this coordinate".  You may be able to tell it to exclude sections of the page within the top half inch and the bottom half inch.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @tim-roberts is relevant. Document AI doesn't detect "headers" and "footers" by default. And Document AI doesn't edit PDF files, if that is what you are looking to do.

If you want to ignore the header/footer text in the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) JSON output, you can use the [code samples for OCR](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#code_samples) to determine the first and last text on a given page up to a certain character index, and remove it during post-processing, or use the page dimensions and `Token` fields to determine the coordinates and remove the page text that is within a margin of the top/bottom.